# type hinting a class as argument to another class having different namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, type-hinting

i don't have much intuitive knowledge on type hinting and namespaces. So i made up the following code to work with both of the concepts.I have three php pages holding three classes and an index.php file inside same directory.They are--

> 1.Student.php
>
> 2.Institution.php
>
> 3.enroll.php.
>
> 4.index.php

i want to use both the `Student and Institution` class inside the `enroll` class.I applied `namespaces` in `Student and Institution` and `enroll` class.And `use` them inside enroll class.But something isn't quite right here.I am getting these errors: ***"it is saying i should pass enroll\student instead of student\student "***

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   enroll\enroll::__construct() must be an instance of enroll\student,
>   instance of student\student given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\typehint\index.php on line 9 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\typehint\enroll.php on line 5

***can anyone explain what is wrong here and how i can fix this ?***

**student.php**

```
namespace Student;
 class Student{

     public $name;

     public function __construct($value){
        $this->name=$value;
     }

 }
```

**institute.php**

```
namespace Institute;
   class Institute{

      public $institute;
      public function __construct($val){
         $this->institute=$val;
      }
   }
```

**enroll.php**

```
   namespace enroll;
      class enroll{

          public function __construct(Student $student,Institute $institute){
             echo $student->name.' enrolled in '.$institute->institute.' school .';
          }
      }
```

index.php:

```
include 'institute.php';
include 'student.php';
include 'enroll.php';

  $institute=new institute\institute('GLAB');
  $student=new student\student('zami');
  $enroll=new enroll\enroll($student,$institute);
```

Comment: Just as a heads up this line: `publci function __construct($value){` in student.php might want to be `public function...` instead.

Comment: sorry i have corrected it before..editing the post

Comment: `public function __construct(\Student\Student $student,\Institute\Institute $institute){`

Comment: or apply a use clause after `namespace enroll;` like `use \Student\Student, \Institute\Institute;`

Comment: @MarkBaker your solution seems work..can you explain a bit why it works ?

Comment: Because you're actively specifying the namespaces that the `Student` and `Institute` classes exist in, otherwise PHP assumes that they exist in the current namespace (`enroll`)

Comment: why i have to use \student\stuent, why not only \student ?

Comment: @AL-zami Because your namespace + class are both called `student`

Comment: Because `\student` is only the namespace, not the class inside that namespace

Comment: Perhaps you should start reading a few tutorials on namespacing before trying to apply it; it's not simply an extension to your class names - http://daylerees.com/php-namespaces-explained/

Comment: Consider namespaces to be like folders. If you try to open a file Student while being in the Institute folder, it won't work. You need to say you want Student/Student, i.e. student file in a student folder, or Student class in a Student namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construct function in enroll class is typehinting the Student and Institute classes as belonging to the enroll namespace, this is the reason for the error. In order to typehint the classes from Student and Institute namespaces you just need to use them:

enroll.php

```
namespace enroll;

use Student\Student;
use Institute\Institute;

class enroll{

    public function __construct(Student $student,Institute $institute){
        echo $student->name.' enrolled in '.$institute->institute.' school .';
    }
}
```

There is no need to load the files as the enroll.php file is loaded last in index.php